# what happened when mysql insert a table reach wait_timeout limit

Tags: mysql, locking

We have the following MySQL task in a bash script:

```
INSERT INTO  blah blah blah;


ALTER TABLE table RENAME TO table_OLD;
```

Right now the MySQL INSERT query runs for over 11 hours, and still not finished.  Then ALTER table query starts, making itself waiting the metadata lock because the INSERT query is still running (according to the "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST & SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS").

What happened when mysql inserts a table which reaches wait_timeout limit, which is 8 hours.  Once the limit is reached, will MySQL keeps running it while un-locked the inserted table?   Thanks!

Here are some tests: when the INSERT INTO passes over 1 sec, the INSERT INTO query still shows running and finally finishes. What does "Wait_timeout" limit really do? After reading the MySQL user manual, I am still quite confused. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) Any thoughts?

```
SET SESSION wait_timeout = 1;

SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE "wait_timeout"; -- 1

INSERT INTO  blah blah blah;


ALTER TABLE table RENAME TO table_OLD;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it would disconnect from the DB forcing you to reconnect thus cutting out the connection for the insert

Found this website that was quite useful: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-set-no-timeout-to-mysql

Just a summary here on removing the timeout from DigitalOcean

```
Edit your my.cnf (MySQL config file)
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

then

```
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800

The interactive timeout does not affect any web application connections. A high interactivetimeout but a low waittimeout is normal and is the best practice.

Choose a reasonable waittimeout value. Stateless PHP environments do well with a 60 second timeout or less. Stateful applications that use a connection pool (Java, .NET, etc.) will need to adjust waittimeout to match their connection pool settings. The default 8 hours (wait_timeout = 28800) works well with properly configured connection pools.
```